# if (viewportwidth >= elementwidth) in CSS?

Tags: css

I want to build a website to present a webcomic. The main objective of the programming is to **always present the full comic page without cropping, and as large as possible**, on all screen sizes and orientations, but allow the user to zoom and scroll.

I would like a layout that does the following (with pseudocode):

```
if (viewportwidth >= (viewportheight * 3/2) + headerwidth) {
                            #  ^ comic width calculated from viewport height !
    comicheight = viewportheight;
    header = in sidebar;
    navigation = in sidebar;
```

[image]

```
} else {
    comicwidth = viewportwidth;
    header = as header;
    navigation = as footer;
```

[image]

```
}
```

I have been breaking my head over this for almost a week now, but I can either get a fixed layout (always header or always sidebar) to fluidly scale to different screen sizes, or fixed size elements (always x pixels) to fluidly change their layout, but not both.

The only solution seems to me to have @media rules for ever single pixel increment of viewport width, but that will be *a lot* of code, and I want to avoid that.

Is there some way to:

- get the viewport dimensions (both width and height)
- calculate which is larger (landscape or portrait orientation)
- calculate if the width of the viewport in landscape is wide enough to fit both the comic scaled to viewport height and the header side by side
- place the elements

**in CSS?**

I would like to [avoid JavaScript](http://www.leaseweblabs.com/2013/07/10-very-good-reasons-to-stop-using-javascript/). But if you have a *light* solution (without including or linking to whole libraries such as jQuery) and a graceful fallback, I'm interested in hearing your suggestion.

The solution must work on all common mobile devices and all desktop browsers from IE 8 upwards.

---

Sample page. You may need to add tags.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="page-Type" page="text/html;charset=utf-8">

    <title>Comic</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <style type="text/css">
        @-ms-viewport {
            width: device-width;  /* IE knows no meta viewport tag */
            }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="header">
        Logo
    </h1>
    <img src="http://www.scifinow.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/The-Hole-Of-Tank-Girl-graphic-novel-review-300x200.jpg" alt="comic"><!-- scale this ! -->
    <p id="nav">
        ‹ previous next ›
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Will the size of the comic strip vary? If so, that is going to make for quite a difficult problem for CSS, not to mention a confusing layout. If not, it may be doable. Or, if the size of the comic strip will change *based on* the viewport...

Comment: @BoltClock The comic will always have the same aspect ratio (width = height * 3 / 2). The size should scale to viewport size (either height or width, depending on orientation), that's the whole point: show the comic as large as possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that width css

us this for changing layout position

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    // do somthing
}
```

and for with of your colums write by percent

http://jsfiddle.net/v5x1otza/

Comment: When I drag down the top border of the result window, the layout does not change. It should change dependent on the aspect ratio of the viewport, not at a fixed pixel width.